Experimental setup has not defined or measured their impedance properly?
I am reading this paper "Impact of Circuit Impedance on Signal Crosstalk" and they made traces of three impedances (4.7Ohms, 50Ohms and Infinite).
I doubt their experimental setup, as they could have used a TDR (time domain reflectometer) to measure the actual impedance of their traces in reference to the return plate. Instead, I think they just terminated their traces with 4.7R, 50R and some MΩ resistors.
Terminating the traces with ideal resistors does translate to a flat impedance across the frequency range, but in the paper they do not even mention the use of resistors to create the impedance of the traces. The closest thing I can find regarding resistors is where they say

The various resistors used were joint to the circuits via connectors
instead of additional wire

And I think the most important proof that they got their impedance wrong, is that they managed to have these three different impedances with the same wires and the same distance of the wires from the return plate/path:

Not to mention that an "infinite" impedance is an odd way to define a large impedance, which does have a measurable value.
This is not just a random website talking about impedance, this is an actual published paper so one would assume there is some weight on its research which I fail to understand.
So reading this paper, is their way of defining impedance correct?

What makes you think this paper has been published in a peer-reviewed journal? It appears to be something like a term paper, written by an undergraduate, that has just been formatted in a journal style and uploaded to a document sharing site --- there's no indication of "publishing" in the academic sense at all.

The authors are using the term 'circuit impedance' to describe the value of resistor they put at the far end of the line.
They do not mention the 'characteristic impedance' of their lines. However, they do specify the lines' geometry and dielectric environment, from which we could estimate their characteristic impedances if we wanted.
Their experimental setup is well defined, and could be replicated and simulated. However, RF engineers might well design the experiment differently.

Hm, I was not aware that circuit impedance and characteristic impedance were used differently.

@ChristianidisVasilis Yes, you have to read their words carefully. 'Circuit Impedance' is not a recognised term, so it means whatever they want it to mean. 'Characteristic Impedance' of a transmission line is well-defined.
